# Deleting a huge number of files at root

Tags: google-drive-api

By mistake I saved a huge number of files at the root of my google drive (>100k files). I cant delete them online easily.

I'm currently trying to delete them by using the [file list api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and the [file delete api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete), it works but it is really slow.

Also I didn't find a way to count how many files remains at the root to estimate how much time this will take.

Does anyone have a faster way to delete the files, or a way to count them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Drive REST API provides a batch method for making multiple requests at once, and completes faster than doing your requests one at a time. You can see the full reference for making batch requests [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#batch-example-request), including code snippets for supported languages. You can use the below python code snippet to make a batch delete request to the Drive REST API:

```
listOfFileIDs = [] 

def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if not exception:
        print(response)
    else:
        print(exception)

batch = vals.service.new_batch_http_request(callback = callback)

for file_id in listOfFileIDs:
    batch.add(vals.service.files().delete(fileId = file_id))

print(batch.execute())
```

You should populate `listOfFileIDs` by making a `Files: list` request to get a list of the IDs of the files you want to delete.

[Things to remember](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#overview):

- You can only make up to 100 calls per batch so you will still need to make multiple batch requests to the server
- `listOfFileIDs` can also only be of maximum 100 length due to this batch limit
- Batch requests are quicker and use less of your quota than individual requests

You can keep a track of your project's requests at the [Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard). The app quota has a courtesy limit of 1000 requests per 100 seconds per user, as well as a few other quota limits which you can see on [the quota tab for you application](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas). You also might need to throttle your request rate using [Exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff) if you keep receiving [`403: Rate limit exceeded`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_rate_limit_exceeded) or [`403: User rate limit exceeded`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to be your only option.  Yes the api is slow but its a free api that you are not paying for.

I would do a file.list first with a q parameter of something like this

```
'root' in parents and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

This will return all of the files that are in your root directory.  Then you can just loop though deleting them one at a time.